# Flake8 uses system python instead of virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, flake8

My flake8 is giving different outputs to a colleague's, and the difference seems to be in the python version:

```
(hydro2) andrew@xxx $ flake8 --version
3.5.0 (mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.3.1, pyflakes: 1.6.0) CPython 2.7.12 on Linux
```

Whereas on his machine it says `CPython 3.5.0` or so.

I'm running the flake8 installed inside a python 3.5 virtualenv, and everything seems to point to the right place:

```
(hydro2) andrew@xxx $ which python
/home/andrew/virtualenvs/hydro2/bin/python
(hydro2) andrew@xxx $ python --version
Python 3.5.2
(hydro2) andrew@xxx $ which flake8
/home/andrew/virtualenvs/hydro2/bin/flake8
```

So I'm just confused as to why it's using `CPython 2.7.12` (which is my OS's default) instead of the virtualenv's version?

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling flake8 in the virtualenv.

Comment: `head -1 $(which flake8)` to inspect shebang in the script. If it's `#!/usr/bin/python` the script uses system python. Edit it to be `#!/usr/bin/env python` so that `env` runs any `python` from the `$PATH`.

Comment: It was set to this `#!/home/andrew/virtualenvs/hydro2/bin/python3`

Comment: Then it's strange — Python should be 3.5 there.

Comment: I know, and it's still a mystery :-)

Comment: No solution/workaround to this? I have a student on a Mac having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

To run a command line tool from a virtual environment you use `python -m`

Therefore, to run flake8 from your virtual environment:

`python -m flake8`

This assumes that you activated your virtual environment.